# php HP cloud Creating Signatures for FormPOST python to php translation

Tags: php, python, hmac

I am currently trying out the HP cloud object storage API but all their examples are in Python and I'm working in PHP.
It's saying my signature is invalid, if anyone can help see where I'm going wrong, I've attached the python example https://docs.hpcloud.com/api/object-storage/#formpost as well as my attempt in PHP.

```
import hmac
from hashlib import sha1
from time import time

path = '/v1/12345678912345/container/object_prefix'
redirect = 'https://myserver.com/some-page'
max_file_size = 104857600
max_file_count = 10
expires = int(time() + 600)
tenant_id = '12345678912345'
access_key_id = 'GP54NNRN2TKBVWH449AG'
secret_key = 'EHLzysK9S1QRWkwvVpVHsGZyM715OH4S2kJ'
hmac_body = '%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (path, redirect,
max_file_size, max_file_count, expires)
signature = tenant_id + ':' + access_key_id + ':' + hmac.new(secret_key, hmac_body, sha1).hexdigest()
```

And this is my attempt...

```
<?php
$expires = time()+600;
$hmac_body = 'https://region-a.geo-1.objects.hpcloudsvc.com/v1/xxx/'.'http://www.test.com/test.php'.'41943040'.'1'.$expires;
$signature = 'tenant_id:access_key:'.hash_hmac(sha1,$hmac_body,'secret_key', FALSE);
?>
<form action="<?php echo 'https://region-a.geo-1.objects.hpcloudsvc.com/v1/xxx/';?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.test.com/test.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="max_file_size" value="41943040" />
<input type="hidden" name="max_file_count" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="expires" value="<?php echo $expires;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<?php echo $signature;?>" />
<input type="file" name="testupload" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If anyone could provide a translation from python to PHP for the hmac_body and the signature I'm sure that would help greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the newlines:

```
mac_body = '%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (path, redirect,
              ^^--^^--^^--^^-- newlines

$hmac_body = 'https://blahblah/xxx/'.'http://blahblah/test.php'.'41943040'.'1'.$expires;
                                    ^--here                    ^--here   etc....
```

Comment: I really though it would work but it's still saying invalid signature

Comment: This doesn't work either

    $hmac_body = 'https://region-a.geo-1.objects.hpcloudsvc.com/v1/xxx/'."\n".'http://www.test.com/test.php'."\n".'41943040'."\n".'1'."\n".$expires;

Comment: Awsome man you're a genius, the http only need to be used in the form, the abbreviated url was in the signature. Thanks so much for the help